# CSS background image strange very strange i just cant get it

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have a strange problem and I just can't solve it. I guess the problem is in the image files. I have a folder called project, inside I have two folders named images and web - my files are in web.
In images I have total of 4 images. I'm trying to set background-image and the problem is its only working with 1 of the 4 images. I use this and it works:

```
body{
 background-image: url("../images/space.png");
}
```

And when i change it - Nothing!? :) :D

```
body{
 background-image: url("../images/123.png");
}
```

It works with 1 img file but not with others.
And a few minutes ago it was working fine... 
I know its really simple question for some, but I'm just getting into html/css.

Comment: Can you show html/css code?

Comment: CSS can be case-sensitive. png is not the same as PNG etc.

Comment: if possible attached you 123.png image on your question. Or you can check  manually with right click on your web page  using inspect(Google Chrome) / inspect element(Mozilla Firefox). Also clear your browser cache memory .

Answer (score 0):

Just tryed random png picture and it works fine. The picture that iam trying to set its also png and 3hrs back it worked, then stoped... I just dont know what to say :D Picture number 3 is jpg, was working perfect too before 3hrs, not anymore..
I've just lost several hours with this pictures, still dont know how to explain it.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Please check if all images in `.png` format. 
Perhaps other 3 images are `.jpg`.

It is hard to understand what is wrong with your project without watching on it. Maybe you could upload all files to some place? Maybe the size of images is so different that you can't see it in the image container.

Comment: That was the first thing i decided may be the problem. And 2 of the 4 pics are png. Space.png works fine 123.png nothing...  and both are .png